# How to solve this Room "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type": which method?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-room

error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
^

```
@Dao
interface BooksDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM books_table")
    fun getAll(): List<Books>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM books_table WHERE book_id LIKE :bookid LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun findByBookid(bookid: Int): Books

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(books: Books)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(books: Books)

    @Query("DELETE FROM books_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Comment: Please add your `Books` entity. May it has any column which is not convertable into Database. Did you used  `@TypeConverters`  for any column?